# scala overriding a map

Tags: scala

I'd like to extend:

```
case class Response(request: String, errors: Map[Any, Any])
```

with something a more specific map, but this:

```
case class ResponseForJerkson(override val request: String, override val errors: Map[String, String]) extends Response(request, errors)
```

isn't working.

Missing something obvious I think?

Comment: BTW, You can workaround your problem using type parameter: 

    `case class Response[T](request: String, errors: Map[T, T]);`
    `case class ResponseForJerkson(override val request: String, override val errors: Map[String, String]) extends Response(request, errors)`

Answer (score 3):

Well, you clearly cannot do this because `Map[A, B]` is not covariant in `A` and `B`. Just trying this out would have given you a detailed compilation error:

```
scala> class A(val m: Map[Any, Any])
defined class A

scala> class B(override val m: Map[String, String]) extends A(m)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Map[String,String]
 required: Map[Any,Any]
Note: String <: Any, but trait Map is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
       class B(override val m: Map[String, String]) extends A(m)
                                                              ^
```

It would work with covariant types:

```
scala> class C(val m: List[Any])
defined class C

scala> class D(override val m: List[String]) extends C(m)
defined class D
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend @oxbow_lakes' answer a bit. "Not covariant" means that `Map[String, String]` is not a subtype of `Map[Any, Any]`. And you can see why it isn't:

```
def foo(response: Response) = response.errors.get(0) // legal, because 0 is an Any
```

But if `response` was actually an instance of `ResponseForJerkson` and `errors` had type `Map[String, String]`, this would be illegal. So there are operations on `Response` which are illegal for `ResponseForJerkson`, and therefore it can't extend `Response`.